# Traefik IngressRoute. How to direct traffic to only one pod?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I have an ingressroute configuration:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: demo-rr-camunda-bpm-platform-app-ingress-route1
  namespace: bpm
spec:
  entryPoints:
  - bpm
  routes:
  - kind: Rule
    match: PathPrefix(`/bpm/demo-rr-camunda-bpm-platform-app`)
    services:
    - kind: Service
      name: demo-rr-camunda-bpm-platform-app-service1
      port: 5000
  tls:
    secretName: k8s-code-ru-tls
```

With this configuration, if two replicas are running, when you try to request a login, the page is displayed from one pod, and the authorization attempt flies to the other pod (and does not work). It is necessary that both the login page and the authorization URL work on the same pod.

If I'm not mistaken, then the solution to this problem is to use `Stickiness` https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/services/

If so, then I cannot figure out how to apply this code to the existing ingressroute that I described above:

```
## Dynamic configuration
http:
  services:
    my-service:
      loadBalancer:
        sticky:
         cookie: {}
```

Comment: I found a solution https://community.traefik.io/t/cannot-enable-sticky-sessions-on-kubernetes-service/4075

Answer (score 0):

you should use kubernetes service which will track your deployment (with 2 replicas) using labels. the service will do the job for you, and Ingressroute will serve the two replicas

Comment: Can you write an example?